# DB many-to-many relationship integrity update

Tags: mysql, sql

The DB has `order` and `customer` tables, along with `order_customer` many-to-many table. For simplicity, let's say `order` has `id` and `customer_id` (the latter field is not needed for many-to-many relationship, but it's left for historical reasons) fields and `order_customer` has `id`, `order_id` and `customer_id` fields. Also all tables have `deleted_at` field (yes, it's laravel) -- NULL if the row is not deleted.
I did some integrity checks to know if the old field `customer_id` is needed at all.

```
    select `order`.`id`, `order`.`customer_id`
    from `order`
    where
    `order`.customer_id not in (
    select customer_id from order_customer
    where `order_customer`.deleted_at is null
    #and `order_customer`.order_id = `order`.`order_id`
    )
    and
    `order`.deleted_at is null;
```

returns 25 rows. So I simply added that `order.customer_id` field in account.
But now I'm asked to fix all integrity issues within `order` and `order_customer` tables.
So I did a simple program in `python` to check all the 3 cases:

1. `order.custmer_id` is not present within `select customer_id from order_customer where order_id = order.id`
2. `order_customer.order_id` is not present within `select id from order`
3. `order.id` is not present within `select order_id from order_customer`

```py
import mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': '***',
  'host': '127.0.0.1',
  'database': '***',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ("select `order`.`id`, `order`.`customer_id` "
         "from `order` "
         "where `order`.deleted_at is null"
         )

cursor.execute(query)

orders=list(cursor)

query = ("select `order_customer`.`order_id`,`order_customer`.`customer_id` "
         "from `order_customer` "
         "where `order_customer`.deleted_at is null"
         )

cursor.execute(query)

m2m=list(cursor)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()

print len(set(c for i,c in orders)-set(c for o,c in m2m))
```

```py
25
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(set)
>>> for o,c in m2m:
    d[o].add(c)

>>> len(d)
40983
>>> len(set(i for i,c in orders if i in d and c not in d[i]))
37
>>> s=set(i for i,c in orders);x=[(o,c) for o,c in m2m if o not in s]
>>> len(x)
1377
>>> x[:10]
[(15968, 2), (98, 3), (109, 3), (115, 3), (1199, 3), (1200, 3), (3626, 3), (3843, 3), (4303, 3), (4681, 3)]
>>> max(o for o,c in x)
37653
>>> len(m2m)
42122
>>> len(orders)
39628
```

but I need these things in `SQL`.

**the main part -->**

```
select `order`.id,`order`.customer_id,
(select 
`order_customer`.customer_id
from `order_customer` where
`order_customer`.order_id = `order`.id) as customer_ids
from `order`
where
customer_id not in customer_ids;
```

does not work at all, but I need something similar to include within `insert`/`update` queries.
Thanks.